# Extending numpy argmin argmax

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ufunc

I am extending my own data types from numpy and almost everything works. I have both `__array_ufunc__` and `__array_finalize__` that converts all the universal functions to my own type. However for argmin and argmax the `__array_ufunc__`, `__array_finalize__`, or `__array_wrap__` is not called. what mechanism should be used for extending these functions and why this is not happening ?

Comment: I think this question might be better suited for the numpy mailing list

Answer (score 1):

I just realized that argmin and argmax use `__array_function__`  mechansim and not universal function one.